# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header Ajax - PHP

Tags: php, ajax

I have i problem with an ajax call

from site A:

```
 function getNativeAdvJson(nick){
    getAdv(nick);
    var newArray = new Array();
    nick_cliente=nick;
    origine=self.location.href;
         URL = LINK_BASE_URL_GHOST;
    var o = { 'nick_cliente': nick_cliente, 'origine': origine, 'azione':     'visualizzazione' };
    newArray.push(o);
    $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:URL,
    async: false,
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
     data: { jsonp: newArray }
    });
}
```

PHP PAGE

```
     header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); 
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Content-Range, Content-Disposition,     Content-Description');
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

and i have that error

XMLHttpRequest cannot load PAGE PHP. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'site A' is therefore not allowed access.

how i can resolve it?

thanks

Comment: You might want to start by making your `$.ajax` call make sense. `POST` and `jsonp` are incompatible. `async: false` is evil, and also incompatible with with `jsonp`. `crossDomain: true` is pointless unless you are making a request to the same origin and then redirecting to a JSONP end point on a different origin.

Comment: Look at the Net tab of the browser's developer tools. Do you see the Ajax request being made? Is it the request you expect (i.e. is the data in it right and is it whichever of GET and POST you actually want?)? What is the response? Is the response what you expect?

Comment: visualizzaJsonHome.js
GET
application/javascript
demoHome3.html:
OPTIONS
403
Forbidden
text/html

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests